# How to set up http input plugin with logstash

Tags: docker, docker-compose, logstash, logstash-configuration, opensearch

Hello I am unable to send http requests to my logstash http input. I receive a server returned no response message. I am able to send requests to my tcp endpoint using cat. I am also able to send http requests to my endpoint when running it from the cli as `docker exec -it`. I don't know what else to try at this point

I am using:

1. opensearchproject/opensearch-dashboards:latest as kibana.
2. opensearchproject/logstash-oss-with-opensearch-output-plugin:7.16.2 as logstash
3. opensearchproject/opensearch:1.2.3 as elasticsearch

My docker-compose file looks as follows:
version: '3.7'

```
services:
  elasticsearch:
    build:
      context: elasticsearch/
    volumes:
      - ./elasticsearch/config/opensearch.yml:/usr/share/elasticsearch/config/opensearch.yml:ro,z
      - elasticsearch:/usr/share/elasticsearch/data:z
    ports:
      - "9200:9200"
      - "9300:9300"
    environment:
      - node.name=elasticsearch
      - discovery.type=single-node
      - "OPENSEARCH_JAVA_OPTS=-Xms512m -Xmx512m"
      - discovery.seed_hosts=elasticsearch
      # - "DISABLE_SECURITY_PLUGIN=true"
    networks:
      - elk

  logstash:
    build:
      context: logstash/
    volumes:
      - ./logstash/config/logstash.yml:/usr/share/logstash/config/logstash.yml:ro,z
      - ./logstash/pipeline:/usr/share/logstash/pipeline:ro,z
    ports:
      - "5044:5044"
      - "5000:5000/tcp"
      - "5000:5000/udp"
      - "9600:9600"
      - "8080:8080"  
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch
    expose:
      - "5000"
      - "8080"
  kibana:
    build:
      context: kibana/
    volumes:
      - ./kibana/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml:/usr/share/kibana/config/opensearch_dashboards.yml:ro,z
    ports:
      - "5601:5601"
    expose:
      - "5601"
    environment:
      OPENSEARCH_HOSTS: '["https://elasticsearch:9200"]'
      # - "DISABLE_SECURITY_DASHBOARDS_PLUGIN=true"
    networks:
      - elk
    depends_on:
      - elasticsearch

networks:
  elk:
    driver: bridge

volumes:
  elasticsearch: null
```

logstash/pipeline/logstash.conf

```
input {
    beats {
        port => 5044
    }
    http {
    port => 8080

    }
    tcp {
        port => 5000
    }
}

output {
    opensearch {
        hosts => "https://elasticsearch:9200"
        user => "admin"
        password => "admin"
        ssl_certificate_verification => false
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

After almost a week, I just figured it out. When specifying the ports I must include  /tcp for port 8080.
ports:

- "5044:5044"
- "5000:5000/tcp"
- "5000:5000/udp"
- "9600:9600"
- "8080:8080/tcp"